# Button Icon Bar won't show up on website - bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

the little icon bar (the three line thing) won't show up in my website, its there but I think it might not be corresponding to my dreamweaver maybe? Helppppppppp

```
<header role="banner">
<nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32877/logo-thing.png" width="200" alt="Logo Thing main logo"></a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header><!-- header role="banner" -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `navbar-default` class in `<nav class="navbar">`.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```